# XSLT document function doesn't work in chrome

Tags: xml, google-chrome, xslt

I am trying to transform a XSLT using Javascript and trying to get it to work on Both Chrome and IE. Entry page is `a.html`. It's working fine in IE (both native/compatibility mode) but doesn't work in Chrome correctly i.e. dropdown is not created with options.

In chrome, however, if I open `data.xml` which has:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="render.xslt" ?>
```

directly in chrome, it is transformed perfectly fine. But if I try to do that same using XSLTProcessor, it doesn't work. Specifically, the `document` function doesn't work. Could you please help?

My code is as follows.

Javascript:

```js
var MSXML2_DOMDocument_6 = "MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0";
function tranform(xml, xsl) {
    if (window.ActiveXObject || "ActiveXObject" in window) {
        var xmlSerializer = new XMLSerializer();
        var xmlString = xmlSerializer.serializeToString(xml);
        var xslString = xmlSerializer.serializeToString(xsl);

        var xsl = new ActiveXObject(MSXML2_DOMDocument_6);
        xsl.setProperty("AllowXsltScript", true);
        xsl.setProperty("AllowDocumentFunction", true);
        xsl.resolveExternals = true;
        xsl.async = false;
        xsl.loadXML(xslString);

        var xml = new ActiveXObject(MSXML2_DOMDocument_6);
        xml.resolveExternals = true;
        xml.preserveWhiteSpace = true;
        xml.async = false;
        xml.loadXML(xmlString);
        xml.resolveExternals = true;

        ex = xml.transformNode(xsl);
        document.getElementById("example").innerHTML = ex;
    } else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument) {
        xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
        xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
        resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml, document);
        document.getElementById("example").appendChild(resultDocument);
    }
}

function loadXMLDoc() {

    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "data.xml",
        dataType: "xml"
    }).then(function (xml) {
            console.log("done xml")
            $.ajax({
                method: "GET",
                url: "render.xslt",
                dataType: "xml"
            }).then(function (xsl) {
                console.log("done xsl")
                tranform(xml, xsl)
            })
        },
        function (e) {
            console.log("Got error in xml", e.status)
        })
}

$(loadXMLDoc)
```

foo/b.xml:

```
<dropdowns>
  <dropdown name="xyz">
    <option value="I">Info</option>
    <option value="C">Category</option>
  </dropdown>
</dropdowns>
```

data.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="render.xslt" ?>
<catalog name="xyz" />
```

a.html:

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script src="jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="example"></div>
    <script src="b.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

render.xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:import href="util.xslt" />
    <xsl:output method="html"></xsl:output>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <h1>
            <xsl:value-of select="/catalog/@name"></xsl:value-of>
        </h1>
        <xsl:call-template name="dropdown">
            <xsl:with-param name="listname">xyz</xsl:with-param>
            <xsl:with-param name="value" select="/catalog/@name"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

util.xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html"></xsl:output>
    <xsl:template name="dropdown">
        <xsl:param name="listname"/>
        <xsl:param name="value"/>
        <select>
            <xsl:for-each select="document('foo/b.xml')/dropdowns/dropdown[@name=$listname]/option">
                <option>
                    <xsl:attribute name="value">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </option>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </select>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am sorry it's a bit long to be an MVE example but it's complete.

Please let me know if any clarification required.

Comment: Could you try and give `document()` an absolute URI parameter (or alternatively use `xml:base` to set a context URI)? If it works with `<?xml-stylesheet?>` chances are the composition of the URI goes wrong. Does the console give error messages?

Comment: I tried with absolute URL, but it still doesn't work. The console gives `Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type application/xslt+xml:` for both `render.xslt` and `util.xslt`. Would that be a cause of the issue?

Comment: I don't know. According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6715767/what-content-type-should-be-used-for-xmlxsl-presentation#8185070 the expected content type should be `text/xsl`, so you could try and tell your webserver to use that for delivery of `.xsl` files (though I doubt it'll help)

Comment: @imhotap - Is it possible to set it to `text/xsl` anywhere?

Comment: Depends on your webserver. Before venturing into that you might want to try and run everything from a `file:` URL first (eg. copy all resources to local directory respecting the relative paths then open the main file using Chrome) to see if it helps at all; though you might need to change your Ajax call

Comment: Chrome's security policy doesn't allow to import or document reference it seems.

Comment: I think the open Chromium bug https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=718434 describes your problem, seems nobody is working to fix it.

Comment: @MartinHonnen - Is there a workaround that I can implement to get around this please?

Comment: A js hack or xslt trick?

Comment: I am not aware of any, at https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt/2018/test201806080102.html I have tried to preload the secondary XML document with Javascript and XMLHttpRequest and then pass it as an `xsl:param` to XSLT, to avoid the use of the `document` function. However, while Firefox swallows that attempt just fine, Chrome doesn't like it and doesn't seem to be able to process the XML DOM document parameter passed in.

Comment: About how mime types are determined by browsers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26303098/1019850

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a workaround<sup>[1]</sup> for this problem.

In chrome, `<xsl:import>` works correctly when transforming in Javascript. So, I converted my XML into XSL `<xsl:choose>` with `<xsl:when>` for each `dropdown` tag.

Update `util.xslt`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html"></xsl:output>
    <xsl:template name="dropdown">
        <xsl:param name="listname"/>
        <xsl:param name="value"/>
        <select>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when name="$listname='xyz'">
                    <option value="I">Info</option>
                    <option value="C">Category</option>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </select>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

<sup>1. I agree that this is not a very good workaround and certainly not a generalized one. If someone has a better solution, please post it as an answer.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

In general the whole approach is about nested templates.
This is already answered here: [How to traverse a nested XML structure using templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198094/how-to-traverse-a-nested-xml-structure-using-templates)

**Below are still some issues and clarifications about the comments below the question.**

Having adjusted the local server that it delivers the file `util.xslt` as Content-Type `text/css` like expected by chrome instead of `application/xslt+xml`, the scripts still never work like expected. Therefore there must be still another issue related to chrome.

[image]

The interesting point is that there are two xslt-documents while one is transferred and accepted by chrome with `application/xslt+xml` but the other one only as `text/xml` or `text/xsl` (yes, both are accepted by chrome, I tried).

Therefore an [interesting post about versions of xml / xslt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13752836/chrome-says-resource-interpreted-as-stylesheet-but-transferred-with-mime-type-a) might not be useful concerning this problem.

Below are the console-messages in detail:

[image]

The adjustment of the server has been done with the following lines, that changes the `Content-Type` (mime-type) if the requested filename has the suffix `xslt` and the expected mime-type is `text/css`:

```
<If "%{REQUEST_FILENAME} =~ m#\.xslt$# && %{HTTP:Accept} =~ m#^text\/css#">
    Header set "Content-Type" "text/css"
</If>
```

**FireFox**

It might be noteworthy that firefox is hiding `util.xslt` in the network-panel completely:

[image]

Furthermore Firefox accepts both methods, ActiveXObject and XSLTProcessor. Depending on the logic in JavaScript the default is set to ActiveXObject, that version looks also smoother concerning the animation of the dropdown.

Firefox is complaining when the xml-version is set to 1.1, therefore playing with 
version numbers might not really help to increase browser-compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

This is known issue and opened since 2009. Also Chrome team don't have any plan to fix it even, they are in planning to remove it's support from chrome (Not sure when). But there is one workaround for this issue. transform your xml data into xslt and then you can import that in to stylesheet.

so you javaScript code will remain same.

foo/b.xml will become foo/b.xslt

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template name="dropdowns">
    <xsl:param name="listname"/>
    <xsl:param name="value"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$listname='xyz'">
            <xsl:call-template name="option">
                <xsl:with-param name="value">I</xsl:with-param>
                <xsl:with-param name="label">Info</xsl:with-param>
                <xsl:with-param name="selectedValue" select="$value"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
            <xsl:call-template name="option">
                <xsl:with-param name="value">C</xsl:with-param>
                <xsl:with-param name="label">Category</xsl:with-param>
                <xsl:with-param name="selectedValue" select="$value"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>

    </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="option">
    <xsl:param name="label"/>
    <xsl:param name="value"/>
    <xsl:param name="selectedValue"/>
    <option value="{$value}">
        <xsl:if test="$value = $selectedValue">
            <xsl:attribute name="selected">selected</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="$label"/>
    </option>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

util.xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:import href="foo/b.xslt" />
<xsl:output method="html" />

<xsl:template name="dropdown">
    <xsl:param name="listname"/>
    <xsl:param name="value"/>
    <select>
        <xsl:call-template name="dropdowns">
            <xsl:with-param name="listname" select="$listname"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="value" select="$value"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </select>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

render.xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:import href="util.xslt" />
<xsl:output method="html"></xsl:output>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <h1>
        <xsl:value-of select="/catalog/@name"></xsl:value-of>
    </h1>
    <xsl:call-template name="dropdown">
        <xsl:with-param name="listname">xyz</xsl:with-param>
        <xsl:with-param name="value">C</xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With these changes you can create drop-downs in you page which will work in both IE and chrome.

Comment: No AFAIK, Chrome don't support that. there is no way to import xml file as Document function is not doing it's job.